# Сombine mutations in one in Strawberry Graphql

Tags: python, django, graphql, strawberry-graphql

How to combine mutations in one?

```py
@strawberry.type
class Mutation1:
    @strawberry.mutation
    def login(self, email: str, password: str) -> LoginResult:
```

```
@strawberry.type
class Mutation2:
    @strawberry.mutation
    def create_post(self, title: str, text: str) -> CreatePostResult:
```

```py
schema = strawberry.Schema(mutations = ....)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In [Strawberry GraphQL](https://strawberry.rocks) you can combine queries and mutations by extending them, for example you can do the following:

```
import strawberry



@strawberry.type
class Query:
    hi: str 


@strawberry.type
class Mutation1:
    @strawberry.mutation
    def login(self, email: str, password: str) -> str:
        return "hi"

@strawberry.type
class Mutation2:
    @strawberry.mutation
    def create_post(self, title: str, text: str) -> str:
        ...

@strawberry.type
class Mutation(Mutation1, Mutation2):
    ...

schema = strawberry.Schema(query=Query, mutation=Mutation)
```

Here's the example in the playground: https://play.strawberry.rocks/?gist=a9117f949453d980f3d88bf88462fd30

Answer (score 1):

To combine multiple mutations, create *one* class `Mutation` and give it multiple methods, each one annotated with `@strawberry.mutation`:

```
@strawberry.type 
class Mutation: 
    @strawberry.mutation 
    def login(self, email: str, password: str) -> LoginResult:
        pass
    @strawberry.mutation 
    def create_post(self, title: str, text: str) -> CreatePostResult:
        pass
# Finally register both Mutation and Query (if defined) to the schema:
schema = strawberry.Schema(query=Query, mutation=Mutation)
```

Similarly, to combine multiple queries, create *one* class `Query` and give it multiple `fields`:

```
@strawberry.type
class Query:
    name: str
    stock: int
```